# Display alternating items below their previous sibling

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML markup,

```html
<div class="entry">
  <p><a href=""><img src="1.jpg"></a></p>
  <p>Sources: www.example.com</p>
  <p><a href=""><img src="1.jpg"></a></p>
  <p>Sources: www.example.com</p>
  <p><a href=""><img src="1.jpg"></a></p>
  <p>Sources: www.example.com</p>
</div>
```

I can't change the html. I want to style it like this:

```
| Image | | Image | | Image |

 Sources   Sources   Sources
```

I have tried this code:

```
p:nth-child(odd) {
    float: left;
    width: 260px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}
p:nth-child(even) {
    display: none;
}
```

But I don't have any idea how to display the sources of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS flexbox with `order` property to display items in specific order without changing the HTML order:

```css
.entry {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.entry > p {
  width: 33%;
}
.entry > p:nth-child(2n+1) {
  order: 1;
}
.entry > p:nth-child(2n+2) {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry">
  <p><a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff"></a></p>
  <p>Sources: www.example1.com</p>
  <p><a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff"></a></p>
  <p>Sources: www.example2.com</p>
  <p><a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff"></a></p>
  <p>Sources: www.example3.com</p>
</div>
```

Ideally, I would change the HTML markup so that image and its source is wrapped in one element.

Answer (score 0):

```css
p {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your CSS with this code:

```
p:nth-child(odd) {
float:left;
display:block;
width:260px;
padding:10px;
margin:5px;
}
p:nth-child(even) {
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While it may be time consuming, you should make your elements and their hierarchy reflect your desired layout of them on the page. For example, each associated piece of content you should wrap in a div and then you can float each of them to the left to have them appear in a row. When you float divs make sure to clear the float below the last floated element or else the elements below will cross over into those above. Also, you should try and refrain from wrapping elements in other elements just to have them automatically inherit the default styles from those elements. So you should remove the p tags from around the images and replace them with divs.

HTML:

```
<div class="entry">
  <div class="item">
    <div class='image'><a href="#"><img src="1.jpg" /></a> </div>
    <p class='sources'>Sources: <a href="#">www.example.com</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class='image'><a href="#"><img src="1.jpg" /></a> </div>
    <p class='sources'>Sources: <a href="#">www.example.com</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class='clear'></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.entry .item {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.entry .item .image {
  //whatever styles you want for the image
}
.entry .item .sources {
  //whatever styles you want for the sources
}
.entry .item .
.entry .clear {
  clear: both;
}
```